# Is it possible that in server-socket programming of bluetooth server waits for client even after client was connected in disconnected once

Tags: c#, android, sockets, bluetooth

Actually I want to make my blutooth server continuously waiting for client.
And once client connects to server, doing some execution; and disconnects from server.

This functionality works fine.

But the problem is that after disconnecting, server do not wait for client again.

Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Comment: It sounds like a bug in your code. In order to receive help, you need to show us what you did.

Comment: @BitBank is it possible to restart server after client disonnected ??